# REGEXP_REPLACE expression

Tags: regex, teradata

I have comments data in text in a column like `ADDED AB SEGMENT FROM *ABCDEF FOR BAG`. I am trying to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to return `ADDED AB SEGMENT FROM *ZZZZZZ FOR BAG` instead as the common/same value in all the occurances of this comment in the column. Can you please help me on this? The `*ABCDEF` occurs usually in the same position for all comments in the column

Comment: On which language you are trying to use Regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
REGEXP_REPLACE('ADDED AB SEGMENT FROM *ABCDEF FOR BAG', 'FROM \*......', 'FROM *ZZZZZZ' );
```

or

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE( <your column>, 'FROM \*......', 'FROM *ZZZZZZ') from <your table>;
```

Comment: I have a REGEXP_REPLACE written for the other values in the same column which is

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE(<my column>, ' *([0-9]{1,2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)|[0-9]{1,4}/[0-9]{1,2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)|[0-9]{1,2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC).|[0-9]{1,2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)[0-9]{1,4}|[0-9]{1,2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC) [0-9]{1,4}|[A-Z]{1,6}|[A-Z]{1,6} [0-9]{1,2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC))$','',1,1,'i')

Comment: i need to combine/include the REGEXP_REPLACE( <your column>, 'FROM \*......', 'FROM *ZZZZZZ') as well to my original regexp_replace...Can you please help me with that?

Comment: You could replace `<your column>` with your complete `regexp_replace(...)`.  Rewriting your regex ... give me some time.

Comment: thank you it worked. I have few values in my data like 'REVIEWED BY DATA ANALYST XXXXXXXXXXXX' and 'FF XX XXXXXXXXX'. I am trying to write a REGEXP_REPLACE for this to return just 'REVIEWED BY DATA ANALYST' and 'FF XX'. Just the 1st four words in the first example and the first two words in the second example and ignore the rest. Can you please help?